# Preload/cache ResolvedModel3D on visionOS?

Tags: visionos

Is there a way to pre-load ResolvedModel3D objects, so that they can be shown without a delay (instead of via Model3D)? Right now there's a delay while models are loaded; I'd like to front-load that time so that the eventual appearance is quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I could see with Model3D. Even loading the same model multiple times doesn't seem to cache it in any way.

However if you use `RealityView` instead then it's possible. You can preload a model with `Entity(named:)` then show that within a RealityView when ready by adding the model to the view's content.

```
struct PreloadView: View {
    @State var showModel = false
    @State var entity: Entity?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if (showModel) {
                RealityView { content in
                    if let entity {
                        content.add(entity)
                    }
                }
            }
            Button(showModel ? "hide" : "show") {
                showModel.toggle()
            }
        }
        .task {
            entity = try? await Entity(named: "VintageGramophone")
        }
    }
}
```